# daterangepicker not working inside ng-if

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ng-if

I'm using daterangepicker in a form field to display a date-picker.
As you can see this works fine in the field at the bottom but it doesn't in the field that is contained within the `ng-if`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/WogKyUDNAVAXQTm3lOJR?p=preview

It's not daterangepicker specific, this is true for any jQuery functions inside an `ng-if`.

One of the solutions involves using `ng-show` but it needs to be `ng-if` in this case.

Comment: `ng-if` removes the dom if the condition is not met. This means your jquery is already executed and the element is not present. Hence when the `ng-if` evaluates to true, you only have the text input. On the other hand `ng-show` is more of a show hide behavior. So the element is present and your jQuery is able to transform it.
Also `ng-if `means more dom manipulations because of removing and adding element to the dom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

1. Wrap the jQuery function inside a $scope function.
2. Call the $scope function with `ng-init`.

   $scope.initializeDatepicker = function(){
       $('.datepicker').daterangepicker();
   };

   ng-init="initializeDatepicker()";

Comment: Consider using angular-bootstrap https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ instead of initializing manually.

Answer (score 0):

Using ngDoCheck() angular life hooks which checks called during eveey changes..after ngOnachanges and Oninit